# KQL Time Series to group time range - Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a dataset with columns StartDate and EndDate. I'm trying to get a count of how many items were 'active' at any given time step. For example: If item has StartTime 01/21/2021 and EndTime 03/22/2021, it would increment 01/2021, 02/2021, 03/2021.

I feel like this has something to do with Timeseries, but I can't wrap my head around it.

```
let data=datatable(startTime:datetime, endtime:datetime)
[
datetime(2021-07-07), datetime(2021-07-13),
datetime(2021-07-02), datetime(2021-09-09),
datetime(2021-06-21), datetime(2021-06-21),
datetime(2021-06-21), datetime(2021-07-23),
datetime(2021-07-07), datetime(2021-07-07),
datetime(2021-07-08), datetime(2021-08-11),
datetime(2021-05-23), datetime(2021-08-23),
]
```

output:

```
Month           Count
2021-05         1
2021-06         3
2021-07         6
2021-08         3
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a slight variation on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuredataexplorer#chart-concurrent-sessions-over-time):

[execute on web explorer help cluster](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42SwW6DMAyG7zyFj0ECtTBt7Tb1EXbabtM0ucWFSCRhiSnt1IdfAl3XiSIVWSj589n5rbgmhgIZV%20HHuK5JOEbLb1LRUzgh9qsESBf8T4rhPQL//e5FPs%20zdL7wESdjNbuLkwk%20H/OPPq7zD2mejflBvZ1fpPm0n6v%20gzrBL8f8Ms0m/Nz3N4/53s/HcxSeIZrNAJ2TpQbUIAtgA4SbCoyVpdRYA%201IMwgn9YaAK%20nAR1chQ0fQoT/zKRvTao6jIziyEmv5TXAE2rN/StAra7pP3ao1WRGYk/6KqqnJwQos6vJiFs4TkEBWhAS1S2nf4EWOv5IPDZmtOM/IX%20EXo7nyZfuCZqvCVpwy49Bw7xZaLb9aGvpz0JCFngxNtEqhDU0UPSp0DOvDUPcHDQAuK8UCAAA=)

```
let data=datatable(startTime: datetime, endtime: datetime) [
    datetime(2021-07-07), datetime(2021-07-13),
    datetime(2021-07-02), datetime(2021-09-09),
    datetime(2021-06-21), datetime(2021-06-21),
    datetime(2021-06-21), datetime(2021-07-23),
    datetime(2021-07-07), datetime(2021-07-07),
    datetime(2021-07-08), datetime(2021-08-11),
    datetime(2021-05-23), datetime(2021-08-23),
];
data
// assign an id to each original event (since this is what we want to count)
| serialize | extend n=row_number()
| extend Samples = range(startTime, endtime, 1d)
| mv-expand Samples to typeof(datetime)
| extend Month = startofmonth(Samples)
// count unique events per month
| summarize dcount(n) by Month
```