# How to perform a SQL PARTITION on KUSTO without using partition?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, database-partitioning, kql

I would like to perform a *SELECT* with a *RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [EventId]* desc) on Kusto, but with the "partition" operator I am limited to max 64 distinct rows. Is it possible to overcome this?

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide an example that includes a small sample input table and the expected output (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125874/kql-time-series-to-group-time-range-kusto/69125921#69125921))

Answer (score 1):

The new syntax `hint.strategy` allows a higher number of partitions. There are two options: `native` for low cardinality columns and `shuffle` for a high cardinality (e.g more than a million)

Here is an example:

```
StormEvents
| where State startswith 'W'
| partition hint.strategy=native by InjuriesDirect (summarize Events=count(), Injuries=sum(InjuriesDirect) by State)
```

The documentation will be published shortly.